# how to inject service into controller using service object name?

Tags: angularjs

I have downloaded AngularJS - ToDo Application from http://www.tutorialspoint.com/angularjs/ and trying to implement same as it is. As I am new in AngularJS, I am stuck somewhere.

In this app AngularJS service " localStorage" is included by object name 'store' in controller. But when I am trying to do this it couldn't work for me.

```
mainApp = angular.module('mainApp', ['ngRoute']);

mainApp.config(function($routeProvider) {
  'use strict';

  var routeConfig = {
    templateUrl: 'template/add_todo.html',
    controller: 'addToDoController',
    resolve: {
      store: function(todoStorage) {
        // Get the correct module (API or localStorage).
        return todoStorage.then(function(module) {
          return module;
        });
      }
    }
  };

  $routeProvider
    .when('/', routeConfig)
    .otherwise({
      redirectTo: '/'
    });
});

mainApp.factory('todoStorage', function($http, $injector) {
  'use strict';

  // Detect if an API backend is present. If so, return the API module, else
  // hand off the localStorage adapter
  return $http.get('/api')
    .then(function() {
      //return $injector.get('api');
    }, function() {
      var store = $injector.get('localStorage');
      return store;


    });
})

mainApp.factory('localStorage', function($q) {
  'use strict';

  var store = {
    todos: [],
    insert: function(todo) {
      store.todos.push(todo);
      console.log(store.todos);
      return store.todos;
    }
  };

  return store;
});

mainApp.controller('addToDoController', function($scope, store) {
  'use strict';

  $scope.addTodo = function() {
    var newTodo = {
      title: $scope.newTodo.trim(),
      completed: false
    };

    $scope.saving = false;
    store.insert(newTodo)
    $scope.newTodo = '';

  }
});
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I am using resolve in config and injected localStorage in to this. So it should be like provider.
and  when trying to use it ( store ) as provider it couldn't work for me.. hope you understand my question..?

Comment: and exactly i am not getting that what i did wrong.